# How to remove a record from a Listbox control in my WPF application with VB.Net code behind

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, listbox

I know similar questions to mine have been posted before, but I have tried various suggestions and nothing seem to work.

Here is my issue:  I get the following error when trying to remove an item\from my listbox control:
*Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.*

I need help removing an item from a listbox in WPF with VB.Net code-behind.
When I click a row in the listbox, I want to remove that item from the listbox.
I create alist of object 'ToLoadImages' to load into my listbox.

How would I remove the selected item from the list box and from my list ob object 'ToLoadImages'?

See my code below:

**'CODE TO LOAD Listbox**

```
Private Sub GetListToLoad(ClaimNo As String) 
 Dim ta As New ImagesDataSetTableAdapters.usp_SELECT_ImageTableAdapter
 Dim dt As ImagesDataSet.usp_SELECT_ImageDataTable = ta.GetData(1, _ClaimNo, True)

 Dim dr As DataRow

 ListToLoad = New List(Of ToLoadImages)
 Dim i As Integer = 0
 For Each dr In dt
        Dim ImgSource2() As Byte = DirectCast(dr(7), Byte())
        Dim stream2 As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream
        stream2.Write(ImgSource2, 0, ImgSource2.Length - 1)
        stream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        bitMap2 = New BitmapImage
        bitMap2.BeginInit()
        bitMap2.StreamSource = stream2
        bitMap2.EndInit()
        ListToLoad.Add(New ToLoadImages(dr(0), bitMap2))
    Next

    ImageListBox.ItemsSource = ListToLoad
  End Sub
```

**'Code to retrieve selected item from the listbox
'Here is where I want to add the code that will remove the selected item from my listbox and from the List of 'ToLoadImages'.**

```
    Private Sub ImageListBox_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ImageListBox.SelectionChanged
    Try
       Dim itemsToLoad As ToLoadImages
       itemsToLoad = ImageListBox.SelectedItem

       Dim imageID as String = itemsToLoad.ImgID.ToString


       Catch ex As Exception
       MsgBox("Error encountered.")
       End Try
     End Sub
```

**Class ToLoadImages**

```
    Public Class ToLoadImages
     Private m_imgID As Integer
     Private m_imageX As BitmapImage

     Public Sub New(imgID As Integer, imagex As BitmapImage)
     Me.m_imgID = imgID
     Me.m_imageX = imagex
    End Sub

  Public Property ImgID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_imgID
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
          m_imgID = value
      End Set
    End Property

   Public Property ImageX() As BitmapImage
     Get
         Return m_imageX
     End Get

     Set(ByVal value As BitmapImage)
         m_imageX = value
     End Set
 End Property
 End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ObservableCollection` instead of `List`.

```
ObservableCollection
```

updates the changes automatically